# How to create a native app for a website based on JS, Kendo, and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, objective-c, mobile

Okay, this may be kind of a loaded question. I am familiar with creating iOS apps. I've made a few native ones, but they were stand-alone projects. I used a backend like Parse.com for most of them. I now want to create an app for this website, native if possible.

Can someone explain the process at a high level? I feel like since the website itself relies so heavily on JS and JQuery, it makes sense to make a web app, since making a native one seems like totally starting over.

Is it not possible to just use the app as a kind of front-end for the already existing website? Or is that just basically a web app at that point?

Basically I'd like to get the performance of native, as long as it doesn't mean re-writing everything.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Alex. Welcome to StackOverflow. We expect questions here to be objectively answerable, i.e. the cause of error message, etc. Your question is subjective in nature and will lead to extended discussion and mostly opinion. Please read through FAQ to ensure that you ask good questions that will not be closed: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: FWIW, though, I believe Telerik's Icenium IDE (http://www.icenium.com/) actually lets you build native apps using just web technologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way from html5/web app to native ios/android app
Is by using phonegap

U can write js/CSS html app and run it as a web site or native app

It's completely free and open source

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) is incredibly useful when writing websites for mobile.

As far as having to create a native app for mobile, unless you really need to optimize your website to the millisecond, you can use both the jQuery Mobile library and the jQuery/jQuery UI library without seeing any noticeable performance drop.

And for the process, developing for mobile is pretty much the same thing as for desktop although you need to keep in mind the mobile limitations/differences (screen size, finger vs mouse precision, etc) and your jQuery is gonna use different events (ie. tap instead of click).

Hope this helps!